# how can "depends_on" in docker-compose be replaced for rancher catalog

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

```
Error (Unsupported config option for srv service: 'depends_on')
```

I become this error by trying to run container in rancher catalog.

```
srv:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2.6.1
  container_name: registry-srv
  depends_on:
    - web
  volumes:
    - ./config/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml
    - ./data:/var/lib/registry
    - ./certs:/certs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-compose up` will start services in dependency order. In your case, it will start the service web before starting the `srv` service. But you have not specified the service `web`. so it will show the error. Either specify the `web` service or remove that line from the `docker-compose.yaml` file